# Somar registros de um campo e exibir no PHP (os valores possuem R$ na frente)

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Olá, estou tentando fazer a soma de alguns valores utilizando o `SUM`  e está retornando **0**.

Os campos que irei utilizar:

1. categoria
2. mes
3. **valor** (quero somar esse)

Quero somar o `valor` de todos os registros de cada categoria e exibir ao lado da mesma categoria.

**Código:**

```
  // SELECT NOS CAMPOS A SEREM EXIBIDOS
  $result_transacoes = "SELECT categoria, mes, sum(valor) FROM contas WHERE mes = 'JANEIRO' GROUP BY categoria ORDER BY categoria ASC";
  $resultado_trasacoes = mysqli_query($con, $result_transacoes);
  while($row_transacoes = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_trasacoes)){

    $html .= '<tr><td>'.$row_transacoes['categoria'] . "</td>";
    $html .= '<td>'.$row_transacoes['mes'] . "</td>";
    $html .= '<td>'.$row_transacoes['sum(valor)'] . "</td>";
  }
```

*Eu comecei tentando somar o valor total de cada categoria, porém, não deu certo, está retornando "**0**", talvez por causa do **R$**? O que eu posso fazer nesse caso? tentei utilizar o **`SUM`***.

Comment: Olá @Sam, os valores estão sendo salvo com `R$` sim, eu removi todos os `R$` da coluna para fazer um teste, porém a soma deles não bateram, alguns ficaram como: **6041.0294810302**, e outra preocupação é, como vou colocar uma mascara de valor monetario em um input sem salvar o `"R$"` ?

Comment: @Sam, removi os `"R$" "." ","` e coloquei como `INT`, aparentemente acho que deu certo a soma, mas não to conseguindo dividir o valor por 100, tentei colocar no propio select, assim: `SELECT categoria, mes, sum(valor)/100 FROM contas`

Comment: Cara, é uma coisa simples e não estou conseguindo... fiz assim: `$valor_dividido = 'sum(valor) / 100';

    $html .= '<td>'.$row_transacoes['$valor_dividido']. "</td>";`

Comment: O certo seria assim: `$valor_dividido = $row_transacoes['sum(valor)'] / 100;` e aqui seria: `$html .= '<td>'.$valor_dividido. "</td>";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sugiro trabalhar com valores monetários numa coluna tipo INT e salvar os valores em centavos. Por exemplo, R$10 (ou R$10,00) você salva com o valor 1000 (mil centavos).

Ao puxar o valor da coluna, você divide por 100 e terá o valor real, com os centavos separados por ponto (ex.: `1000` ficará `10.00`). Por exemplo, se o valor for 150000 (cento e cinquenta mil centavos) que é equivalente a R$1.500,00 (mil e quinhentos Reais) você irá dividir por 100 e usar a função [money_format()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.money-format.php) do PHP para apresentar o valor com a formatação do Real brasileiro, inclusive já acrescentando o símbolo R$. Um exemplo:

```
<?
setlocale(LC_MONETARY,"pt_BR");
$valor = "150000";
echo money_format("%n", $valor/100); // R$ 1.500,00
?>
```

É preciso usar o `setlocale` para definir a formatação. A linha `setlocale(LC_MONETARY,"pt_BR");` deve ser definida apenas uma vez. Você pode colocá-la num include geral do site porque já irá ficar ativa no ambiente do site todo, sem ter que declarar novamente.

Comment: Não entendi......

Comment: Use a máscara normal. Quando vc enviar o valor para o PHP, antes de salvar no banco, vc deve converter para centavos. Por exemplo, se vc enviar 12,00 (doze reais), vc elemina a vírgula antes de colocar no banco.

Comment: Antes de colocar no banco vc faz um replace tirando a vírgula e o ponto. Use `str_replace`. Ou seja, 1.200,00 vai virar 120000.

Comment: Tentei dessa forma: `<script>
      // NAO IR PARA O BANCO
      function formatar($valor){
       $pontos = array(",", ".", "R$");
       $result = str_replace($pontos, "", $valor);
       return $result;
      }
     </script>` , porém o valor é zerado no banco...

Comment: Cara, não consegui utilizar o  `replace` até agora, quando ele remove o `"."` ou `","` ele apaga o valor que está em seguida... exemplo: 1.500,00 , o banco só salva o 1

Answer (score -2):

Tudo bem Samuel? Vamos lá!

Você pode resolver isso na sua query e seu código vai ficar mais limpo. Apenas adicione `group by categoria` antes do `order by` que já resolve.

Este trecho de código cria um agrupamento em nível de categoria e a soma automaticamente virá separada por categoria.

OBS: Necessário remover o **R$** com o trecho de código `REPLACE(valor, "R$", "")` e depois converter o texto pra decimal. Veja na query no link abaixo.

Veja o exemplo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4766a1/3

Comment: Olá tiago, a parte da categoria funcionou, mas creio que a soma dos valores não... parece que pegou só o primeiro valor de cada categoria. Com o `sum(valor)` os valores ficaram zerados. Será que não é por causa do **R$**?

Comment: Está correto @Samuel. Fiz a correção na resposta.